# How do you inset inwards from the outer edges ONLY?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I don't even know how to properly phrase this, but here is what i want:

[image]

[image]

And here is what i'm getting:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that middle face part of the shape for your inset? If so you'll have to include it in your selection for your inset, like so:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

If it is not part of the shape then you can temporarily fill it, perform the inset, then remove the extra face from the shape.